# pytester - testdir can not find the pytest plugin

Tags: python, pytest

I have created a sample plugin. I want to test it with pytester pluging. Doc reference:https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#testing-plugins

However, the pytester does not seem to find the plugin which needs to be tested.

Please find the file_setup I have done.

```
poc_plugin
|- pytest_myplugin
|  |- plugin.py   
|- setup.py
|- pytest.ini
|- tests
   |- conftest.py
   |- test_myplugin.py
```

Please find the files I have created

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name="pytest-myplugin",
    include_package_data=True,
    python_requires=">=3.0, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*",
    install_requires=[
        "pytest>=5.3.5",
    ],
    setup_requires=["pytest-runner"],
    classifiers=[
        "Framework :: Pytest",
    ],
    packages=find_packages(include=["pytest_myplugin", "pytest_myplugin.*"]),
    test_suite="tests",
    entry_points={"pytest11": ["myplugin = pytest_myplugin.plugin"]},
    version="0.1.0",
)
```

pytest_myplugin/plugin.py

```
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    """
    This is a pytest hook to add options from the command line.
    """
    group = parser.getgroup("pytest-jay")

    group.addoption(
        "--jay",
        action="store",
        dest="jay",
        default="package",
        help="A Sample option",
    )
```

conftest.py

```
pytest_plugins  = ["pytester"]
```

tests/test_plugin.pt

```
import pytest


test_sample_txt = """
def test_sample():
    assert True
    """

def test_pluging_one(testdir):
    """Make sure that pytest accepts our fixture."""

    # create a temporary pytest test module
    testdir.makepyfile(test_sample_txt)

    # run pytest with the following cmd args
    result = testdir.runpytest(
        '--jay=jay',
    )

    # fnmatch_lines does an assertion internally
    result.stdout.fnmatch_lines([
        '*::test_sample PASSED*',
    ])

    # make sure that that we get a '0' exit code for the testsuite
    assert result.ret == 0
```

pytest.ini

```
[pytest]
testpaths = tests
```

The output I am getting::

```
C:\Jay\Work\poc_plugin\tests\test_plugin.py:23: Failed
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stderr call ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --jay=jay
  inifile: None
  rootdir: C:\Users\jay.joshi\AppData\Local\Temp\pytest-of-jay.joshi\pytest-46\test_pluging_one0

======================================================================================== short test summary info ========================================================================================
FAILED tests/test_plugin.py::test_pluging_one - Failed: remains unmatched: '*::test_sample PASSED*'
=========================================================================================== 1 failed in 0.26s =====
```

Why testdir can not find the plugin?

Comment: To make the plugin being used in the test case, we need to install it first. Use `pip install -r .` or `python setup.py develop` to install the plugin and then execute the testcase.

Comment: `pytest_myplugin` seems to be missing an `__init__.py`, so `find_packages()` won't find it. Check whether the package contains all files - run `pip install . --force-reinstall`, then `pip show -f pytest-myplugin`, is `pytest_myplugin/plugin.py` listed?

Comment: strangely it worked without `__init__.py`. I just installed the package using `python setup.py develop` & it worked.  I think it should have given an error that it's not a package (without `__init__.py`).

Comment: Does it work in `poc_plugin` directory only? `cd ~` and e.g. `python -c "import pytest_myplugin.plugin"` works?

Comment: It does. I am running python3.7 in Windows. Strange. Maybe I have misconfigured something. I'll try again.

Comment: I don't know how it could work, but testing from scratch on my machine reveals two errors: 1. missing `__init__.py`, so the `pytest_myplugin` package doesn't get included in the dist and 2. you are executing `runpytest` without the `--verbose` flag, so the `test_sample PASSED` output will never be shown, even if the test passes. `testdir.runpytest('--jay=jay', '--verbose')` fixes that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured that the requirement for the `pytester` and `testdir` fixture is that the plugin should be installed in the python environment.

To install the `develop`(current) version of your plugin you can use `-e` param with pip.

```
pip install -e <path_to_plugin>
```

Or you can do similar using `setup.py`

```
python setup.py develop
```

Once the plugin is installed, executing the steps in the question solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried using testdir.plugins and what I normally find is that I need to run w/ a -p, for your case...

```
testdir.runpytest('-p', 'path.to.plugin.module', '--jay', 'bob')
```

alternatively, modifying pytest_plugins may also work

```
pytest_plugins = ['_pytest.pytester', 'path.to.jay']
```